# Is there an adjective meaning a more/less uneven aspect ratio?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, shapes

I'm looking for an adjective for whether a shape is as wide as it is tall, i.e, is a rectangle or ellipses, vs a square or circle. "Rectangular" and the like usually refer to an object's sharp/round angles, not its width/length ratio. Right now I'm getting by making comparisons along one axis ("foo is thinner", "bar's height [which is greater than its width] imports a sense of length to car [which is associated with bar]") but it's not clear I'm talking about *relative* length, or that only foo is a regular/even/1:1AR shape. Is there a direct way to refer to and compare aspect ratios?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@BrianDonovan gave the very appropriate **oblong**, if you're looking for a word sounding more common, **elongated** also fits the purpose—it can mean something that "was made to be longer than wide", but also means "long in relation to width".

About *oblong* note that it seems to qualify only flat objects:

> A rectangular object or flat figure with unequal adjacent sides

(Oxford dict.)

The word describing an aspect ratio close to one without completely prescribing the shape is **rotund**:

> Approximately spherical; round, orbicular

(OED)

Answer (score 7):

The word is ***[oblong](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblong)***:

> longer in one direction than in the other direction (Merriam-Webster, first definition)

Comment: This is the word that immediately springs to mind, and it is undoubtedly right for many things… but somehow, describing a car as oblong sounds quite strange to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: yes, that would be odd, as would describing one of its wheels as round. Some things sound odd because they go without saying. Even a Smart car is 62% longer than it is wide.

Answer (score 3):

The term aspect ratio is used in contexts other than imaging and displays. In [aeronautics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(aeronautics)#Aspect_ratio_of_aircraft_wings), for example, aspect ratio describes the ratio of the length of a wing to it's chord (width). In such circumstances it is quite common to describe a long, narrow wing (e.g. a [sailplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(sailplane))) as having a *high aspect ratio* and a shorter or wider wing (e.g. the [North American X-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_X-15)) as having a *low aspect ratio*.

While this usage appears to be close to what you want to describe and is common terminology for people already familiar with aspect ratios in certain contexts, it may still require further explanation/definition if your target audience is not already familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 3):

The term of art in mathematics is called *eccentricity*. For an ellipse this is defined as the the ratio of the distance from the ellipse's center to one of its foci to the distance from that focus to one its vertices. Here's a pictorial representation:

[image]

The term is applied to other conic figures, and less often to rectangles. From [*Differentiation of Integrals*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2138.pdf) by Shunchao Long:

> ... (the
>   **eccentricity** of a rectangle is the ratio of its longest size over its shortest size).

Comment: I wonder how the etymology relates to the everyday usage of "eccentric" to mean a person is... "far-out", quirky... Eccentric! It fits, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of [computer displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_aspect_ratio), aspect ratios *wider* than 4:3 are also called widescreen.

For [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)) aspect ratios in general wide is also used, and in addition *flat* is applied for some motion picture formats.

*High* usually refers to resolution, not aspect ratio.

References
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_aspect_ratio
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)